# Converting RDD key value pair flatmap with non matching keys to spark dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have a rdd  key-value flatmap with each  each dictionary has the possibility of having different keys . I would like to convert this rdd to a spark dataframe . Whats the best way to approach this problem?

```
records_rdd2 = records_rdd.flatMap(func)
records_rdd2.collect()
[{'name':'test','age':'21','class':'2'},
 {name':'test2','age':'23'}]
```

For the above data I am expecting the following output

```
#+----+----+----+
#|name|age |class|
#+----+----+----+
#+----+----+----+
```

One of the approaches I tried was to save all unique keys to a list and use to_DF to convert rdd to spark dataframe but I  am running into list index out of range error. I suspect this is because of column names not present in every partition.

I have looked into this post [Pyspark: convert rdd with different keys to spark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47526055/pyspark-convert-rdd-with-different-keys-to-spark-dataframe)

Any other ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: `RDD.toDF()` converts the `RDD` to a dataframe. your case is a simple `toDF()` as the column names will come from dict keys

Comment: `RDD.to_DF()` is creating a dataframe with only common keys across the list of dictionaries.

Comment: are you sure? it created all columns in my try.

Comment: Yes. I have a rdd containing 15000 dictionaries and around 500  unique columns but the dataframe i get is 15000 rows with around 200 columns.

Comment: I am running `toDF() `  function after flatmap.

Comment: Did you fix it? What exactly are you applying in 'func'? Because at your example, the second dictionary is generating a null value to class.

Comment: Yes, but I am still looking for an optimized way to implement.
Currently, I am doing this
` df=  spark.read.json(sc.parallelize(records_rdd2.collect())`
but it takes a while to run and there would be memory constraints if input records are huge.